# Add extra custom permissions to Field Permissions

Tags: 8, entities

I'm using Field Permissions module to restrict access to each field.

If you choose `custom permission` on `/admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT_TYPE/fields/FIELD_NAME`, you'll see these permissions are available:

- Enter own value for field [FIELD_NAME]
- Edit own value for field [FIELD_NAME]
- Edit any value for field [FIELD_NAME]
- View own value for field [FIELD_NAME]
- View any value for field [FIELD_NAME]

I would like to add some permissions with extra conditions like 'Edit any value for field [FIELD_NAME] if the field is empty'.

For D7 version of the module there was a hook called `hook_field_permissions_list_alter` but there's no such thing in D8 version.

Is there any way to modify the list?

Answer (score 2):

With Drupal 8, the module implemented the permission type plugins. To add more permissions, you implement a new permission type plugin, using one of the existing plugin classes as example, such as [`Drupal\field_permissions\Plugin\FieldPermissionType\CustomAccess`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/field_permissions/-/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Plugin/FieldPermissionType/CustomAccess.php) or [`Drupal\field_permissions\Plugin\FieldPermissionType\PrivateAccess`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/field_permissions/-/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Plugin/FieldPermissionType/PrivateAccess.php).  [`Drupal\field_permissions\Plugin\FieldPermissionType\Base`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/field_permissions/-/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Plugin/FieldPermissionType/Base.php) is used as base class, and simplifies the creation of new permission type plugins.

Note that the module invokes the `hook_field_permission_type_plugin_alter()` implementations, as described in the [field_permissions.api.php](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/field_permissions/-/blob/8.x-1.x/field_permissions.api.php) file. That hook can just be used to remove a permission type plugin, or change the plugin properties given in its annotation (which doesn't include the permissions exposed from the plugin, for what I can see).